Se puede hacer un modal bootstrap con contenido variable?
me explico... estoy trabajando en una tiendo online donde necesito hacer que se abra un modal al hacer clic bien sea en el titulo del producto o en el boton ver mas etc. El contenido de dicho modal debe variar dependiendo del producto que se seleccione.
    <?php foreach ($data['destacados'] as $destacado) { ?>
  <section class="Contenido-Destacados">
    <h2 class="titulo_destacados">
      <?php echo $destacado['destacado']; ?>
    </h2>

    <div class="container-destacados" id="destacado_<?php echo $destacado['id']; ?>">
      <div class="caja-celeste" id="container-destacados">
      <div class="row-destacados <?php echo (count($destacado['productos']) > 0) ? '' : ''; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($destacado['productos'] as $producto) { ?>
          <div class="<?php echo (count($destacado['productos']) > 2) ? 'destacados' : 'destacados'; ?>">
          <h5 class="oferta_index">70% OFF</h5>
          <div class="contenedor-img-destacados">
            <div class="descript">
              <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <div class="descript-overlay"></div>
                <img class="descript-image" src="<?php echo BASE_URL . $producto['imagen']; ?>">
                <div class="descript-details fadeIn-bottom">
                  <h3 class="descript-title"><?php echo $producto['nombre']; ?></h3>
                  <p class="descript-text"><?php echo $producto['tags']; ?></p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="titulo_producto_destacado"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Details"><?php echo $producto['nombre']; ?></a></h3>
          <div class="price icon-price-tags"><span> S/<?php echo $producto['precio']; ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="box-envio-text">
            <p id="envio_todo_peru"><i class="icon-truck envio_todo_peru"></i>Desde<span> <?php echo $producto['pais']; ?></span></p>
          </div>


        </div>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
      </div>
        <div class="btn-destacados_left"><i class='icon-circle-left'></i></div>
            <div class="btn-destacados_right"><i class='icon-circle-right'></i></div>
    </section>
    <?php } ?>


    <div class="modal fade" style="z-index: 99999;" id="Details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Details" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="Details"><?php echo $producto['nombre']; ?></h5>
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">

            <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide">
              <div class="carousel-indicators">
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
                  <img src="<?php echo $producto['imagen']; ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                  <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
              <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
            </div>



          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer d-grid gap-3 col-10 mx-auto">
            <p class="lead"><?php echo $producto['descripcion']; ?></p>
            <h2><?php echo MONEDA . $producto['precio']; ?></h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Comprar ahora</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar al carrito</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

en el codigo anterior tenemos un carousel llamado destacado el cual funciona perfectamente pero el problema que tengo es que no se como hacer que en el modal que esta fuera del carousel se habra la informacion con los detalles del producto, como lo es el titulo, descripcion, precio, fotos, etc. Esto ha sido un dolor de cabeza para mi ya que apenas empiezo en el backend. Espero me puedan ayudar



Por supuesto que se puede hacer. Una manera muy fácil, añadir un onClick al sitio desde dónde la abres y que guarde en sessionStorage la información que quieres pasarle, y luego simplemente en la modal pintas lo que haya ahí guardado

@Benito-B eso no es dinamico ... para que se guarde en sessionStorage debe existir una pre carga ... y si los datos tiene media hora ... ya no seria algo dinamico o en tiempo real ...

lo correcto seria armar el modal (oculto) y dejar el contenido vacio.... en un onclick buscar los datos del backend mediante ajax, tomar el resultado y pintarlo, una vez pintado mostrar (hacer el trigger) el modal.

Si lees la pregunta en vez de inventarte la definición de las cosas verás que dice "El contenido de dicho modal debe variar dependiendo del producto que se seleccione.". En ningún momento añade nada de tiempo real. Sería dinámico porque cambia según el elemento seleccionado.

"producto que se seleccione." esto es en tiempo real te imagina precargar 1000 producto ... como que es mucha info innecesaria ... he leido e interpretado correctamente ... por algo estoy desarrollado un WMS.

Estoy tratando de hacer esto desde ayer pero... como hago para guardar una imagen si el session storage almacena solo 5M? Recuerda que necesito el nombre, precio, descripción, imagen y lo que vaya añadiendo luego. Además como pinto la información dentro del modal? Se me hace un poco confuso todo

Pensé que podria hacerlo con sus variables en php pero no sé si será posible también

No, la solución correcta es la que te dijeron, mediante ajax buscas los datos a mostrar y generas el modal. Otra solución, es que por PHP crees todos los modales junto con el producto. El modal estará oculto, pero con los datos ya llenados y luego con el botón ver más lo muestras. Esta opción es bastante simple, pero según el peso de tus imágenes puede dar una pobre performance
